# How to format numbers in excel in crores or lacks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, number-formatting

For example, I want something like 1 cr if we enter in cell 10,000,000. I have tried number formatting like many available but not a single one is doing my job.

[image: Example I want]

Comment: Too few examples, please add explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=TEXT(A1/10000000,"#,### \cr")`